# Does Sonar use Jacoco plugin for the code coverage

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, jacoco

Does Sonar use Jacoco plugin for the code coverage?? Or is it possible if Sonarqube can handle independently the code coverage without using the jacoco plugin??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, SonarQube server accepts reporting in a certain format and hence you could upload different reports to SonarQube server. JaCoCo exec-files can also be uploaded into SonarQube server.

You could get good set of steps [here](https://dzone.com/articles/integration-jenkins-jacoco-and-sonarqube).